# Application access denied - Custom Editor for Sitecore Client

Tags: sitecore-client, security

I am building an editor for the Sitecore client.  However when I load this editor in the content editor, it shows the error `Application access denied`.  I am currently logged in as an administrator.  After researching the issue, I found many had this issue after upgrading with Sitecore editors, but I couldn't find anything about this issue related to those building custom editors.  I assume its related to `read` permissions are needed for my editor, which I tried to apply but that didn't seem to work, so I must still be missing something.

[image: Application access denied.]

Can someone describe the steps needed to allow a custom built editor for the content editor to be configured correctly, so it'll have the correct permissions.

Comment: Dylan is this a custom configured Rich Text Editor profile or something else?

Comment: I'll attach a screenshot but I'm referring to building a custom editor (not rich text editor).  So essentially I am building something like the "Template Builder" but with another purpose.

Comment: Have you tried turning on debugging logging and see if you can locate the access denied item?